# Vue2: how to scroll to bottom when page has image with different height?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scrollbar

I am using vue2 framework. I have a user case like this: need to scroll to bottom when the page first loaded. Currently my solution is like this:

```
this.feeds = feeds // this is the data need to render to dom
this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.isLoaded = true
        let el = document.getElementsByClassName('chat-msgbox-wrap')[0]
        el.scrollTo(0, el.scrollHeight) 
    })
```

Well, for most cases, it can work. The challenge is, when we need to render an image, although in nextTick callback it has already been injected into dom, but the height of the image is not accurate for it maybe changed during render. So the effect is, when I first loaded, the scrollbar is positioned bottom, but after all images fully rendered, the scrollbar is not in bottom, for the image height changes. I consider use `MutationObserver` but it seems can't observe scrollHeight property of element. I there any good method to solve this ? By the way, I can't set fixed height for the image, we only allow to set fixed width and let the height vary.

Comment: how did you do the lazy loading? normally a lazyloader library would have a `load` event handler to handle things after the lazyload completes

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question above, for lazyloader library is not allowed to be imported due to performance consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a useful tool [imageloaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/), we can write a directive based on it.